# Build TYPE for many columns

Tags: sql, oracle, types, execute, bulk

I have below type:

```
TYPE t_my_list is record(col1 VARCHAR2(4000),col2 varchar2(4000),col3 varchar2(4000));
Type  listOfString is table of t_my_list;
```

then Im doing BULK COLLECT:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret;
```

What if I have 20 columns? Doing it as below I think don't make sense:

```
TYPE t_my_list is record(col1 VARCHAR2(4000),col2 varchar2(4000),....col20 varchar2(200);
```

How else build the TYPE?

***UPDATE***:

```
declare
  TYPE                         t_my_list is record(colX VARCHAR2(4000),colY varchar2(4000),ColZ varchar2(4000));
  Type                         listOfString  is table of t_my_list;
  v_stmt      VARCHAR2(32000) := 'SELECT col1, col2, col2 FROM table_TEST';
  v_ret                        listOfString  := listOfString ();

begin
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret;
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_ret = '||v_ret.count);   
    for i in v_ret.first..v_ret.last loop
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('colX: '||v_ret (i).colX||', colY: '||v_ret (i).colY||', ColZ: '||v_ret (i).ColZ);
       --will be done second EXECUTE IMMEDIATE taking as parameter ColX, ColY and ColZ
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: you cat use `Tablename%ROWTYPE`

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Just because it's a lot of typing and maintenance? Without knowing why you're using dynamic SQL or what your query statements will look like it's hard to suggest alternatives - if the select list is static and the schema/table changes for instance then you could maybe use a nominal `%rowtype`, for example. It kind of looks like you're using large text fields to accept any possible value/data type from the query though, which sounds like a problem in itself. A more complete example of what you're trying to do might be useful.

Comment: I put my code.....I'm not allowed to use RowType and cursor, only collections

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for a static query? And are you not able to use `%rowtype` and cursors at all for some reason; or do you mean you are not allowed to use a cursor for loop? Also, are you selecting all columns from the table or only a few? (and did you mean to have `col2` twice?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you really need to use dynamic SQL, so you can declare a cursor statically, then use that cursor's `%rowtype` to create a collection type:

```
declare
  cursor c_my_cursor is select col1, col2, col3 from table_test;
  type t_my_table is table of c_my_cursor%rowtype;
  v_ret t_my_table;
begin
  open c_my_cursor;
  fetch c_my_cursor bulk collect into v_ret;
  close c_my_cursor;

  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_ret = '||v_ret.count);   
  for i in v_ret.first..v_ret.last loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col1: '||v_ret (i).col1||', col2: '||v_ret (i).col2||', Col3: '||v_ret (i).Col3);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This doesn't loop over the cursor, it just opens it, does a single bulk fetch into the collection, and closes it again.

If you are selecting the same column twice for some reason, or if you just want to stick to the X/Y/Z naming (or whatever scheme you want), you can just alias the columns in the cursor query:

```
  cursor c_my_cursor is select col1 as colx, col2 as coly, col3 as colz from table_test;
...
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('colX: '||v_ret (i).colX||', colY: '||v_ret (i).colY||', ColZ: '||v_ret (i).ColZ);
```

Comment: thank you Alex, but I can not use cursor only bulk.....
any way good explanations